# Understanding Bayesian updating: application to distance sensors

Tags: probability, sensors, bayesian

I would need to measure the actual distance `D` of a wall using a distance sensor (both the sensor and the wall are fixed, so that `D` is constant in time). From the Bayesian updating it follows that `P(D|X) ∝ P(X|D)P(D)`, where `P(D)` is the prior, `P(D|X)` is the posterior, and `P(X|D)` is the conditional probability of the measurement `X|D`, whose distribution is estimated based on a sample of 50 values recorded with the distance sensor.

I have the following question: after replacing the prior with the posterior, can I repeat the upgrade by re-using the same sensor? That would mean: `P(D'|X') ∝ P(X'|D')P(D')`, with `P(D') = P(D|X)`.

My answer would be no. Indeed, as the sensor is the same, the two measurements `X'` and `X` are defined by the same random variable. I am not sure if my understanding of Bayes' theorem is correct, but I would imagine that a second update could be done only if I were using a different sensor, whose measurement is totally independent from the measurement of the first sensor. However, if the two sensors were based on the same technology and shared the same manufacturing process, I guess their readings (`X'` and `X`) would be somehow correlated, and again I wouldn't know how to proceed in that case.

Comment: Good question, although it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com for such questions. That said, you can repeat the process with additional measurements from the same sensor, in which case applying Bayes rule twice is (for conventional measurement models) equivalent to applying it once with a data sample comprising the previous and new measurements. Or, you can make additional measurements with a different sensor and integrate those with the other one; the details depend on what you assume about how the sensors work.

Comment: I worked on sensor models as an aspect of the stuff I was doing for my dissertation. Take a look at Chapter 6 in my dissertation, which you can find about half way down the page at: http://riso.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @RobertDodier FYI, close voting supports migrating to CrossValidated.

Comment: @RobertDodier Many thanks for your comments and the useful material. Not being familiar with this topic, I am struggling to understand how you would distinguish the two approaches (using Bayes only once with 100 samples or repeating it twice with 50 samples each time) from a mathematical point of view. Assuming gaussian distributions for both P(D) and P(X|D) one gets a posterior P(D|X) which is also normally distributed, with variance v = 1/(1/v1+1/v2) and mean m = (m1*v2+m2*v1)/(v1+v2), where 1 and 2 refer to P(D) and P(X|D) respectively. How would you account for the number of samples?

Comment: @RobertDodier Also, assume I repeat the measurement process twice but in 2 different scenarios: the first, the measurement is repeated with the same exact sensor; the second, the measurement is repeated with a copy of the first sensor. Should I expect any difference in the results? What if in the second scenario I replace the copy of the sensor with a different sensor (e.g., infrared ipo ultrasonic), which just by a chance is characterized by the same distribution P(X|D)? All these questions are about how to handle the correlation between 2 consecutive measurements in Bayes updating. Thanks!

Comment: It's conventional (not required) to assume that measurements are independent given the actual value, which makes the joint probability of a set of measurements equal to the product of the probability of each one. Given that, you can group the measurements any way you want, and the joint probability is the same. E.g. one group of n, two groups such that n1 + n2 = n, three, four, ... n measurements one at a time. Note that depends on an assumption of independence, which might or might not hold, depending on how the measurement model is set up, but it's the case for many conventional models.